# How i can handle http requests in perl?

Tags: perl, http, cgi

I tried to use CGI.pm (3.15), but it can't handle PUT requests.

I'm building a REST API, so I need methods PUT, GET, POST and DELETE.

Any ideas?

**Code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use CGI;
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);

main: {

print "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n\n";

my $query = CGI->new;
my $value1 = $query->param('param1');
my $value2 = $query->param('param2');

my $data = $query->param('PUTDATA');

print "value1[$value1] value2[$value2] data[$data]\n";
};
```

**Curl**:

```
curl 'http://localhost/cgi-bin/testing.cgi' -X PUT -H 'Origin: chrome-extension://hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch' -H 'Host: 192.168.8.197' -H 'Accept-Language: es-419,es;q=0.8' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.71 Safari/537.36' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -H 'Accept: */*' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' --data 'param1=hola&param2=hola' --compressed
```

value1, value2 and data always empty.

Comment: What do you mean, it can't handle PUT requests???

Comment: Sure it can. Please show your code and errors

Comment: Personally, I'd use [Catalyst](http://jjnapiorkowski.typepad.com/modern-perl/2013/02/catalyst-built-in-support-for-http-method-dispatching-and-whats-next.html#.UfKvV2TOvrY), but I'd be surprised if you can't deal with PUT in CGI.

Comment: This [PerlMonks article](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=920370) might be of some use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it!

The solution was doing an  update to the perl module CGI to 3.63 and now works fine.